# fetch—POST json not working

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I am trying to POST json Data to the server using the fetch API. I have got this code:

```
const post = (url, data = null) => {
  let params = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  return fetch(BASE_URL + url, params);
};
```

When triggered I results in a `400 Bad Request`. After I inspected the Request in the network panel I found the method to be OPTIONS, instead of POST. If I remove the `headers` property the method stays right, but than the server does not recognise the content to be json.